# Checkin details of multiple places in a single request using Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

In Facebook API, is it possible to get the checkin details of multiple places in a single request.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the method to request multiple objects is documented on the first page of the Graph API documentation:

`/checkins?ids=<LIST OF PAGES in CSV FORMAT>`

Of course, you can only see checkins by the current user or their friends, per the Pages documentation

{edit}: Oh, the checkin count is slightly different but you should have been able to determine that from the documentation easily enough:

`/?fields=checkins&ids=<LIST OF PAGES in CSV FORMAT>`

Comment: Thanks for your help, but could you please tell me how to get the checkin count of listed pages in a single request.